# Google calendar API. Modifications loss when simultaneously patching event

Tags: google-calendar-api, etag

I have firebase function that processes webhook.

This function updates calendar event, updating of single event may be simultaneously.

I use Etag and `If-Match` header for prevent modification loss as described in [doc](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/version-resources).

But I still loss all changes except the last.

This code does multiple simultaneous updates with same event.

In result summary must be '10' but actually it is '2'.

What is wrong with it?

**Code**

```js
const calendarId = 'calendarid';
const scopes = [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events",
];
const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({ scopes });
const calendar = google.calendar({ version: "v3", auth });

...

const reproduce = async () => {
  const {id: eventId} = await calendar.events.insert({
    auth,
    calendarId,
    resource: {
      summary: '1',
      // some another resource data
    },
  });

  const update = async () => {
    const event = await calendar.events.get({
      auth,
      calendarId,
      eventId,
    });

    console.log("***BEFORE***");
    console.log("summary: " + event.summary);
    console.log("etag: " + event.etag);
    
    const previousSummary = event.summary;
    const newSummary = parseInt(previousSummary) + 1;

    const res = await calendar.events.patch({
      auth,
      calendarId,
      eventId,
      resource: {summary: newSummary.toString()},
    }, {
      headers: {
        "If-Match": event.data.etag
      }
    });
    
    console.log("***AFTER***");
    console.log("summary: " + res.data.summary);
    console.log("etag: " + res.data.etag);
  }

  let i = 0;
  // simultaneously updates event
  while (i++ < 10) {
    update();
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
>  ***BEFORE***
>  summary: 1
>  etag: "3235006977030000"
>  ***BEFORE***
>  summary: 1
>  etag: "3235006977030000"
>  ***BEFORE***
>  summary: 1
>  etag: "3235006977030000"
>  ***BEFORE***
>  summary: 1
>  etag: "3235006977030000"
>  ***BEFORE***
>  summary: 1
>  etag: "3235006977030000"
>  ***BEFORE***
>  summary: 1
>  etag: "3235006977030000"
>  ***BEFORE***
>  summary: 1
>  etag: "3235006977030000"
>  ***BEFORE***
>  summary: 1
>  etag: "3235006977030000"
>  ***BEFORE***
>  summary: 1
>  etag: "3235006977030000"
>  ***AFTER***
>  summary: 2
>  etag: "3235006998028000"
>  Event updated successfully
>  ***AFTER***
>  summary: 2
>  etag: "3235007000852000"
>  Event updated successfully
>  ***AFTER***
>  summary: 2
>  etag: "3235007002822000"
>  Event updated successfully
>  ***AFTER***
>  summary: 2
>  etag: "3235007003202000"
>  Event updated successfully
>  ***AFTER***
>  summary: 2
>  etag: "3235007004826000"
>  Event updated successfully
>  ***AFTER***
>  summary: 2
>  etag: "3235007009742000"
>  Event updated successfully
>  ***AFTER***
>  summary: 2
>  etag: "3235007011058000"
>  Event updated successfully
>  ***AFTER***
>  summary: 2
>  etag: "3235007014902000"
>  Event updated successfully
>  ***AFTER***
>  summary: 2
>  etag: "3235007018050000"
>  Event updated successfully
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your issue using Javascript in Apps Script.
The reason why you were able to update your event once (which makes your summary "2") is because of your `async/await` command in `update()`.

### Sample Code:

```
 const update =  async () => {
    const event =  await Calendar.Events.get(
      calendarId,
      eventId,
    );

    Logger.log("***BEFORE***");
    Logger.log("summary: "+event.summary);
    Logger.log("etag: "+event.etag);
    const previousSummary = event.summary;
    const newSummary = parseInt(previousSummary) + 1;


    const res =  await Calendar.Events.patch(
      {summary: newSummary.toString()},
      calendarId,
      event.id,
      { "If-Match": event.etag }
     );
    
    Logger.log("***AFTER***");
    Logger.log("summary: "+res.summary);
    Logger.log("etag: "+res.etag);
    //Logger.log(res);
  }

let i = 0;
// simultaneously updates event
while (i++ < 10) {
  update();
}
```

### Output:

```
12:04:47 AM Notice  Execution started
12:04:51 AM Info    ***BEFORE***
12:04:51 AM Info    summary: 1
12:04:51 AM Info    etag: "3234758978180000"
12:04:51 AM Info    ***BEFORE***
12:04:51 AM Info    summary: 1
12:04:51 AM Info    etag: "3234758978180000"
12:04:52 AM Info    ***BEFORE***
12:04:52 AM Info    summary: 1
12:04:52 AM Info    etag: "3234758978180000"
12:04:52 AM Info    ***BEFORE***
12:04:52 AM Info    summary: 1
12:04:52 AM Info    etag: "3234758978180000"
12:04:52 AM Info    ***BEFORE***
12:04:52 AM Info    summary: 1
12:04:52 AM Info    etag: "3234758978180000"
12:04:53 AM Info    ***BEFORE***
12:04:53 AM Info    summary: 1
12:04:53 AM Info    etag: "3234758978180000"
12:04:53 AM Info    ***BEFORE***
12:04:53 AM Info    summary: 1
12:04:53 AM Info    etag: "3234758978180000"
12:04:53 AM Info    ***BEFORE***
12:04:53 AM Info    summary: 1
12:04:53 AM Info    etag: "3234758978180000"
12:04:54 AM Info    ***BEFORE***
12:04:54 AM Info    summary: 1
12:04:54 AM Info    etag: "3234758978180000"
12:04:54 AM Info    ***BEFORE***
12:04:54 AM Info    summary: 1
12:04:54 AM Info    etag: "3234758978180000"
12:04:54 AM Info    ***AFTER***
12:04:54 AM Info    summary: 2
12:04:54 AM Info    etag: "3234758983260000"
12:04:54 AM Info    ***AFTER***
12:04:54 AM Info    summary: 2
12:04:54 AM Info    etag: "3234758983260000"
12:04:54 AM Info    ***AFTER***
12:04:54 AM Info    summary: 2
12:04:54 AM Info    etag: "3234758983260000"
12:04:54 AM Info    ***AFTER***
12:04:54 AM Info    summary: 2
12:04:54 AM Info    etag: "3234758983260000"
12:04:54 AM Info    ***AFTER***
12:04:54 AM Info    summary: 2
12:04:54 AM Info    etag: "3234758983260000"
12:04:54 AM Info    ***AFTER***
12:04:54 AM Info    summary: 2
12:04:54 AM Info    etag: "3234758983260000"
12:04:54 AM Info    ***AFTER***
12:04:54 AM Info    summary: 2
12:04:54 AM Info    etag: "3234758983260000"
12:04:54 AM Info    ***AFTER***
12:04:54 AM Info    summary: 2
12:04:54 AM Info    etag: "3234758983260000"
12:04:54 AM Info    ***AFTER***
12:04:54 AM Info    summary: 2
12:04:54 AM Info    etag: "3234758983260000"
12:04:54 AM Info    ***AFTER***
12:04:54 AM Info    summary: 2
12:04:54 AM Info    etag: "3234758983260000"
12:04:54 AM Notice  Execution completed
```

- Notice that `Calendar.Events.get()` method was executed 10 times before `Calendar.Events.patch()` was executed. Hence you were able to patch your event once.
- I'm not that expert when it comes to Javascript Promises but you might want to remove your `async/await` in your `update()`, `get()` and `patch()`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I still can't understand why multiple simultaneous updates overwrites each other.

Comment: Documentation says I will get a 412 (Precondition failed) response code if event has changed since the last retrieval but this does not happen.

Comment: It did not overwrite each other, what happened was your await command executes your events.get() 10 times first and it did not proceed with your events.patch(). By the time the events.patch() was executed 10 times as well, the etag used in the patch request is based on the last events.get() response after it was executed 10 times. It was proven based on the sample reproduced code and seen in the logs.

Comment: Have you tried removing your async and await to see if the expected output was achieved?

Comment: I've updated my example code by adding log printing like yours.
Also I've added output of my code and I see that overwrites happens because calendar API responses with updated ETag.

Comment: Also I've tried to remove awaits but something went wrong. I can't access to `summary` and `etag` fields of `res` since they are undefined.

Comment: And besides, I see no reason for avoiding promises to make `update()` synchronous. I've made it async specially for reproduce parallel requests to my firebase function.